# Convert asp function to php

Tags: php, asp-classic

Hi i am developing a free shopping basket, I have an asp function taken from google code for there gateway, I have very little knowlage of php and would like some help in the conversion

The Asp Function

This takes the xml that is your shopping basket and does a server to server request, if all is well google will retuen an URL to redirect to

you pass in your XML the url you want to submit to and both your merchant id and key

```
Function SendRequest(Xml, Url, id, key)

    Dim XmlHttp, BasicAuthentication, ResponseXml

      Set XmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
      XmlHttp.Open "POST", Url, false

        Const SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS = 2
        Const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS = 13056

        XmlHttp.SetOption SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS, _
            (XmlHttp.getOption(SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS) - _
            SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS)

        BasicAuthentication = Base64Encode(id & ":" & Key)
        XmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & BasicAuthentication
        XmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8"
        XmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8"
        XmlHttp.Send Xml

        ResponseXml = XmlHttp.ResponseText
        SendRequest = ResponseXml
        Set XmlHttp = Nothing

  End Function
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: It would also make sense to use the PHP code Google offers. http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_PHP.html

Comment: Sorry i dont know how to reply with out doing a full blown question again

any way thank you for the responses, the code google provided is for php 4, I am using 5, not sure how big a issue this is is

so to updaye my question what is the PHP equiv of Set XmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")

Many Thanks in advance Tim Dodgson

Answer (score 0):

The php equivalent of `XmlHttp` is [Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

You should be able to rebuild the function in php5 using curl, Although there is already a prebuilt php5 library

[My php Google Checkout](http://code.google.com/p/myphpgooglecheckout/)

> My PHP Google Checkout is a library
>   written for PHP5 that allows for easy
>   integration with the Google Checkout
>   API and Payment process system. It
>   provides a basic server class for
>   processing notifications, a MySQL
>   implementation that logs and tracks
>   payments in a database, a shopping
>   cart framework for managing items in a
>   cart for for composing your "Google
>   Checkout" button. It is easy to
>   extend, and is perfect for traditional
>   OOP programmers.